# Why does the code always say 'The Number is Smaller"?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm a beginner in python and today I tested out my knowledge by making a Number guessing game. Whenever I try to run it, it works fine, however it always says that the number is lower than my guess.

I can't figure out the problem, so I haven't really tried any solutions.

```
import random

while True:
    print('Welcome! Type "Play" to play. Type "Quit" to Quit the program.')
    choice = input()
    if 'Play' in choice:
        print('Very Well. I am thinking of a number Between 1 and Hundred. Try to Guess it!')
        break
    elif 'Quit' in choice:
        exit()
    else:
        print("Sorry, That's not a valid Function.")
        continue
number = random.randint(1, 100)
GuessesTaken = 0
while GuessesTaken < 13:
    guess = int(input('Enter a Number: '))
    GuessesTaken += 1

    if guess > number:
        print('The Number is bigger than that!')
        continue
    if guess < number:
        print('The number is Smaller than that!')
        continue
    if guess == number:
        print(f'You got it! he Number is {number}! Thanks for Playing!')
        break
if GuessesTaken > 13:
    print(f"Sorry, You're out of Guesses. The number was {number}" )
    exit()
```

Comment: Just change the message output the first should be smaller

Comment: Your program doesn't work that way; it says "bigger" as well, just not appropriately.

Answer (score 2):

You mixed the signs in these `if` conditions:

```
if guess > number:
    print('The Number is bigger than that!')
    continue
if guess < number:
    print('The number is Smaller than that!')
    continue
```

`if guess > number` should be `if guess < number` and vice-versa.

If `guess` is greater than `number` it means it means `number` is smaller, and vice-versa.

Comment: Or reverse the variables, to make it similar to the message.

Comment: @Barmar Or reverse the message ;)